# Can't access customData in view for non-logged in user - Express.js Stormpath

Tags: node.js, express, stormpath

Following this tutorial:

> https://stormpath.com/blog/build-nodejs-express-stormpath-app

I can easily access and display in view **profile.jade**,  customData for logged in user , from **profile.js** with

```
username: req.user.username,
city: req.user.customData.city,
```

**Filename: profile.jade**

```
h1 This is surname #{username} and #{city}
```

---

I want to display in a view, data for a non-logged in user at URL:
http://localhost:3000/-jsmith
which I got working - except I can't access any customData.

**FILENAME: server.js**
I do have this set.

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  expand: {
    customData: true
```

and

```
app.get('/-:id', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('the response will be sent by the next function ...');
        var id = req.params.id;
        next();
    },
    function(req, res) {
        var id = req.params.id;
        req.app.get('stormpathApplication').getAccounts({
            username: id

        }, (err, accounts) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            accounts.each((account, cb) => {
                console.log('Found matching account:', account);
                cb();
                res.render('user', {
                    email: account.email,
                    city: account.customData.city,

                });

            });
        });
    }
);
```

#### The problem:

**Filename: user.jade**

**username** is displayed, but nothing for **city**

```
h1 This is surname #{username} and #{city}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're taking the Stormpath Application object directly and making API calls with it, you'll actually need to add the `{ expand: 'customData' }` parameter to each API call.

I know you've set it for your express-stormpath configuration already -- this only applies to API calls the application makes on your behalf (for instance the req.user). I can see how this may seem confusing.

So to make this work, simply replace:

```
    req.app.get('stormpathApplication').getAccounts({
        username: id
    }
```

With:

```
    req.app.get('stormpathApplication').getAccounts({
        username: id,
        expand: 'customData'
    }
```

And things should work. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly, and simple solution.  I knew I could return a JSON object with all the customData, but this such a simple solution.